# Reuse associated type from protocol in another protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

This is my code:

```
protocol Requester {
    associatedtype requestType

    var response: ((requestType) -> ())? { get set }
}

protocol RequestProcesser: AnyObject {
    // Is it possible to define a associated type that is equal to the associated type of Requester?
    associatedtype requester: Requester

    // This associatedtype should always be equal to Requester.requestType
    associatedtype requestType

    var request: requester { get set }
}

extension RequestProcesser {
    func process() {
        request.response = { response in

            // Now I need to cast...
            // Is there any way around this?
            // the type of the response should be equal to requestType so the cast can be omitted right?
            let x = response as! requestType
        }
    }
}
```

As you can read in the comments in the code, I am wondering if I can constraint associatedtypes in a way they are equal to other associatedtypes in another protocol. The goal is to omit the cast. Now an implementing class can choose a different type for `requestType`, which will result in a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requestType` associated type isn't necessary in the `RequestProcessor` protocol, as it is implicit based on the `requester` associated type.

You should just be able to define the `RequestProcessor` protocol like this:

```
protocol RequestProcesser: AnyObject {
    associatedtype requester: Requester
    var request: requester { get set }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
class MyRequester: Requester {
    typealias requestType = Int
    var response: ((Int) -> ())?
}

class MyRequestProcessor: RequestProcesser {
    typealias requester = MyRequester
    var request = MyRequester()
}
```

Now, the `response` closure parameter inside the `process()` method will take on the associated type of the `MyRequester` protocol (in this case `Int`), so no casting is necessary.